# Calculate mean and std for 1 field in feature class Table (ArcGIS 10.4, arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, statistics

I would like to calculate a mean and STD for one field in my feature class. I am python beginner.

I have found great source calcualting mean and STD for multiple fields, however, the STD calculation seems not correct: [Is it possible to calculate statistics across multiple fields in arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112126/is-it-possible-to-calculate-statistics-across-multiple-fields-in-arcpy) 
After applying the code, my STD is "None" which is not true for real data.

My code:

```
import math, itertools, arcpy

FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
field = "RASTERVALU"

#Flatten a list of lists       # do I even need this if I have just one field? How to replace this?
def flatten(list_lists):    
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_lists))

#Definition of standard deviation, seems not working...
def std(x):
    pass

#read values from fields and flatten
vals = flatten([r for r in row] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FC, field))

# print results    
print "mean is " + str(sum(vals) / len(vals))
print "std is" + str(std(vals))     # STD gives back None
```

How to correctly calculate my STD? I need it to save as a value, which I can use further in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the `std()` function is just to `pass` through the dataset and not to calculate anything. If you want to define it as a function, you need to tell the function what to calculate. While you could write the function to calculate standard deviation, my suggestion would be to utilize the numpy module, which has a mean and stdev function among many other things.

Add to your import statements:

```
import numpy as np
```

and then you can use `str(np.mean(vals))` and `str(np.std(vals))` as parts of the print statement. Also note that np.std returns the population standard deviation (divisor is N) and not the sample stdev (divisor is N-1). You can change this by changing the code to `str(np.std(vals, ddof=1))`.

Comment: Thank you !! seems right for STD calculation! Please, any advice if I need to "Flatten a list of lists" if I am using only one field in the table? How can I replace it?